# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 mac os 10.13.3

Tags: c++, macos, qt, compiler-errors

I know this question was already asked like a thousand times but i tried every solution and nothing helped.

I made a little program in Qt and after a while i got this error message:

```
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I redid the `qmake` command and the rebuild project, nothing worked.
I'm new in Qt.
I am using Qt version 5.10.0 on mac os 10.13.3

Here are my files:

gui.h

```
#ifndef GUI_H
#define GUI_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>

#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLineEdit>

class gui : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    gui(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~gui();

private:
    QHBoxLayout *hbox1;
    QHBoxLayout *hbox2;
    QVBoxLayout *vbox;

    QPushButton *search;
    QPushButton *replace;

    QLineEdit *searchText;
    QLineEdit *replaceText;
    QLineEdit *textField;

public slots:

    void find();
    void replaceFuckingText();
};

#endif // GUI_H
```

gui.cpp

```
#include "gui.h"

gui::gui(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{

    hbox1 = new QHBoxLayout();
    hbox2 = new QHBoxLayout();
    vbox = new QVBoxLayout();

    search = new QPushButton("Search");
    replace = new QPushButton("Replace");

    searchText = new QLineEdit();
    replaceText = new QLineEdit();
    textField = new QLineEdit();

    hbox1->addWidget(searchText);
    hbox1->addWidget(replaceText);

    vbox->addLayout(hbox1);

    hbox2->addWidget(search);
    hbox2->addWidget(replace);

    vbox->addLayout(hbox2);

    vbox->addWidget(textField);

    setLayout(vbox);
    show();

    connect(replace,SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(replaceFuckingText()));

}

gui::~gui()
{

}

void gui::replaceFuckingText() {
    QString searchTextValue = searchText->text();
    QString replaceTextValue = replaceText->text();
    QString textToReplace = textField->text();

    textToReplace.replace(searchTextValue,replaceTextValue);

    textField->setText(textToReplace);
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "gui.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    gui w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I hope you can help me. I'm working on this error for over a week now.
If you need more informations feel free to ask and I'll post them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

on MacOS generally is not difficult to diagnose and generally it comes from something you defined in headers but does not have proper implementation!

to know why exactly you got this message click `Compiler Output` in Qt Creator, most likely you will see where the `make` error is coming from, in your code case I see below error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "gui::find()", referenced
>   from:
>         gui::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) in moc_gui.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

from this message it looks that you have declared `gui::find()` slot or method in a header, but no where in your `cpp` that slot has any implementation!
So all what you need is to add code for slot `gui::find()` in your `cpp` file.

When I add the following to your gui.cpp, the code compiles without issues:

```
void gui::find()
{
    // do some staff
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kanan, Even i am facing a similar problem but here i have not created any user defined function. All things are qt generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really tired and accidentally add the `.cpp` file to `HEADERS` instead of `SOURCES` in your `.pro` file, you can also get this error.